# How can I remove the underline of a link in chrome using CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, hyperlink, underline

(it works in FF)
How can I, using CSS, remove the underline of a visited link? I have tried:

```
a:visited {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

and

```
a:visited {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you set `border-bottom` instead of `text-decoration` for links?

Comment: Can you show us your site with an example?  I'd have expected the example in your question to work in Chrome...

Comment: @Kris C http://phihag.de/2011/so/visited.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only CSS property you can apply on :visited links in most webkit-based browsers (like Chrome) is `color`. This is to prevent [history stealing](http://www.iseclab.org/papers/sonda-TR.pdf). Also, you can't determine the value of the `color` CSS property of links from JavaScript. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24300 for details.

You can, however, change the style of all links with `a{text-decoration: none;}`. [Here's a demo of the whole affair](http://phihag.de/2011/so/visited.html).

Comment: Why do you need `!important`? I don´t see any underlines in Chrome on sites where I have just used `a { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: @jeroen In general, you don't need important if your rule's specificity is greater than that of the text-decoration rule in the built-in default stylesheet. For the color property, many browsers used to declare it in the more specific a:link or a:visited element. Since I can't find any browser needing !important for text-decoration, I removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Some browser-vendors have decided/realised that separately styling `a:visited` hyperlinks represent a security/privacy threat to the user. Therefore some, though not all, have removed the ability to style `a:visited` differently.

I suspect that this is true of Chrome.

References:

- http://djtechnocrat.blogspot.com/2010/12/browser-privacy-css-history-sniffing-in.html
- http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/
- See also this Stackoverflow question: [Google chrome a:visited background image not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788855/google-chrome-avisited-background-image-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

Your `a:visited {}` definition must come *before* your general `a {}` definition. You can use a:visited to set a color, but setting a text-decoration doesnt' work - but if you later set a general text-decoration for a elements, it does.

So:

```
a:visited {color: yellow;}
a {color:yellow; text-decoration: none; }
```

works (gives all links in yellow, no text decoration ever), but

```
a {color:yellow; text-decoration: none; }
a:visited {color: yellow;}
```

and

```
a {color:yellow; text-decoration: none; }
a:visited {color: yellow; text-decoration: none;}
```

don't (both give all links in yellow, but underlined)

Comment: This one is golden. Also note that your styling of that kind cannot be reapllied using JavaScript, at least in Chrome. If you try to reload this kind of a stylesheet you will get them restyled back.