# CSS. Changing image visited link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background-image

I have a image-hyperlink. And I want to change the image when the link have status visited. Could you show me how to do it? Preferably without using JavaScript.

I'm trying to do the following: I joined both my images in single common image and here is my code:

```
<a href="#" class="mylink">
   <img src="common_image.jpg" width="240px" height="240px"/>
</a>
```

And my styles:

```
    .mylink {
        width: 120px;
        height: 240px;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .mylink:visited img {
        margin-left: -120px;
    }
```

Comment: How do you mean "you want to change the image"? Do you want to change the image source?

Comment: I would look into using background-image and css sprites. This should point you in the right direction at least. You can use one image and switch the background-position on :visited.

Comment: Yes, I want to see another image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alter the `src`-attribute of an image throught CSS. If it, for some reason, have to be an `img-element`, then you are stuck with JavaScript for the alteration.

The other alternative would be to get rid of the `img`-element and use only the anchor with a background instead. The `background`-property can be controlled through CSS.

Here is a [simple example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/basic-link-rollover-as-css-sprite/) of how to do it for `:hover`, but in you case `:hover` could just as easy be changed to `:visited` instead.

If you place the "visited"-image below the default image in a file called sprite.png, the code would be:

```
a.mylink {
    width: 120px;
    height: 240px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(sprite.png) no-repeat;
}

a:visited.mylink {
    background-position: 0 -240px;
}
```

See it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZzkY/ (Uses background-color instead of image for simplicity)

Comment: Unfortunately your code didn't work. This solution is suitable for the status hover but not to visited. If replace visited by hover in my variant so it works well too

Comment: @Andrei Please see my updated CSS and example. It appears the right way to write the selector is `a:visited.myLink`.

Comment: @Andrei Does the fiddle work for you? Do you get a yellow background behind google and grey behind unvisited?

Answer (score 1):

Playing with :visited pseudo selector for background image don't work. There is a security limitation in major browsers to prevent snifing exploit.
See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3842816/1458189)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the image and control the background through the css

```
.mylink {
    background:url('myimagepath-01.jpg') top left no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 240px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mylink:visited {
    background:url('myimagepath-02.jpg') top left no-repeat;  
}
```

Comment: Then it wouldn't be one image file any more. That's what the OP is after.

Comment: I think this would mean creating 2 images for each link and assign ids to each one, not practical in the way that the CSS would end up being huge if there were to be multiple links using this effect on a page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="image">Link</a>​
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    background: transparent url('http://javascript.info/files/tutorial/browser/events/rollover-sprite/button.png') no-repeat top left;
    width: 186px;
    height: 52px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.image:hover {
    background-position: 0 -52px;
}
.image:visited {
    background-position: 0 -104px;
}
```

If you want to use sprites, then you should set the image as a css background, and move its position using the `background-position` property. You can see an example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4csmL/).