# background-image: for :visited links?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to add the background-image: property to visited links?

```
 a.coolLinks:visited{
     background-image:url("http://www.ledr.com/colours/black.jpg");
}
```

Thanks

Edit: So it appears that this is a security vulnerability and this is why it cannot be done. There was no indication that the browsers were blocking this css style.

Comment: Did you try it? Should work.

Comment: I think, not 100%, that you can only use `:visited` on a tags. So you need `a.coolLinks:visited { }` for it to work properly.

Comment: I forgot to add the 'a.' it still does not work. Let me add a JSfiddle to the post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is correct according to most specifications.  However, [many browsers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) consider background images on visited links a potential violation of user's privacy, so they do not allow it.

Observe this example:

```
<p><a href="/unvisited">Unvisited link</a></p>

<p><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">Visited Link</a></p>

<style>
a {
  background:red url("http://placekitten.com/100/101?image=2") center center no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

a:visited {
  background:blue url("http://placekitten.com/100/100?image=1") center center no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

(Also at http://jsfiddle.net/Yq5GY/1/).  Firefox ignores the background image declaration for visited links, and never displays the solo kitten. You can do some differentiation with **background color**.  It's bad usability to rely on images alone, anyhow.

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: @KatieK do you have any reference for why browsers would consider it a privacy violation? I can't think of why that would be the case.

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788855/google-chrome-avisited-background-image-not-working)

Comment: @Kevin Boucher: The W3Schools example... not the W3C example

Comment: Ahhh. That explains alot. Funny how the W3Schools example uses background-color: w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp (Guess that's why they are so maligned here)

Answer (score 1):

As @KatieK suggested, most browser would not allow setting a background-image [even some other rules like background-color] to `:visited` links as it is a Privacy Problem. You can read about it using the following links:

1. [Privacy Related Changes](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)
2. [Reported Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147777#c160)

Comment: Hrm, Sharp's demo doesn't seem to work in my Firefox (latest).

Comment: oops, yeah i just realized it does not work with FF4 and above. Sorry about that, Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN spec for :visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3avisited), you will notice background-image is not allowed.