# CSS a:visited background image not applying?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the background image on the 'download' link to change to a green tick once clicked and downloaded. I have applied a:visited, a:hover and a:active, hover is working but somehow a:visited and :active aren't, any ideas why?

```
form.download a:visited{
background: url("../images/tick-active.png") no-repeat 10px 5px;       
}

form.download a:hover{
background: url("../images/tick-active.png") no-repeat 10px 5px;
}

form.download a:active{
background: url("../images/tick-active.png") no-repeat 10px 5px;
}
```

Also, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mbmd/1/)

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle for your problem. You'll have better chance of getting a solution.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because some browsers see it as privacy violation.

**background color** should work. I guess background-images are the problem, because you could see which pages your user has visited by tracking the image requests to your server.

See here:

[background-image: for :visited links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202856/background-image-for-visited-links)

[Google chrome a:visited background image not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788855/google-chrome-avisited-background-image-not-working)

Comment: Background color doesn't work either unfortunately, : http://jsfiddle.net/2mbmd/1/

Comment: Weird. There's a good discussion about that in my first link. This is quoted there: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq5GY/1/

Answer (score 0):

Visited and active of the anchor are based on the URL.

If you are sitting AT the URL that the anchor is pointing to then 'active' is the one that is selected.

Same goes for visited URLs and 'visited'

Comment: Here is a demo page from www.w3schools.com

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link

Answer (score 0):

It is because of [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) options. For JSFiddle it is `SAMEORIGIN`, and this is why `a:visited` doesnt work until `href` is on same origin.

Side note: remember that pseudoclasses works in following order:

1. `link`
2. `visited`
3. `hover`
4. `active`