# How to change a Div background url which is inside a link tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag with a background image, inside a link tag. What I want to do is highlight or change the relevant background image of the div tag once clicked it.

```
<td>
  <a href="../pages/index.php">
    <div id="dashboardDiv" 
      style="background:url(../images/home.png) no-repeat center";)>
    </div>
  </a>
</td>
<td></td>
```

CSS:

```
#dashboardDiv{
    border:thin;
    float:left;
    height: 133px;
    width: 133px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with php? - Also, show us what you have tried

Comment: I added the css and html code used for this on above. Thanks in advance. Please help me as I am new to programming.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202856/background-image-for-visited-links

Comment: Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the visited link:

```
a:visited > #dashboardDiv {
    background-image:url(NEW_URL_HERE) !important;
    /*you can remove !important if you don't style the div inline*/
}
```

If you want the background to change only when the link is clicked you can use the CSS `:clicked` pseudoclass instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response.