# Complex behavior using pseudo-element of a element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a code like this:

```css
a:link {
  background-color: pink;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
<br>
<a href="">link</a>
<br>
<a>link</a>
```

The :link pseudo-class applies to links that have not yet been visited. Therefore, I thought that the `background-color` and `color` properties were canceled in the link after the visit.

> https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#link
> The :link pseudo-class applies to links that have not yet been visited.

But in fact, the `background-color` property remains. Also, does the color of the letter return to the original blue instead of purple?

Is this a known bug that has been reported? Or is there another factor in the specification? This was reproducible on most modern browsers, but no bug ticket was found in any browser to certify this as a bug.

[image]

---

I also found that the visited background is interfering with the link, but this isn't intuitive, but is it spec?

```css
a:link {
  color: yellow;
}

a:visited {
  background: black;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
<br>
<a href="">link</a>-why background not work?
<br>
<a>link</a>
```

[image]

---

**update**

I received a comment about privacy restrictions. However, as far as MDN articles are concerned, it is primarily a constraint on the `background-image` property, and the `background-color` property should not be affected, so this should not be related to the privacy constraint.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#Styling_restrictions
>
> For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit which styles you can apply using this pseudo-class, and how they can be used:
>
> - Allowable CSS properties are color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, column-rule-color, and outline-color.

I'm not convinced that a pseudo-class style that shouldn't be applied is applied if it doesn't have a default style sheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [background-image: for :visited links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202856/background-image-for-visited-links)

Comment: tldr; privacy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#Styling_restrictions or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Comment: @soulshined It is about `background-image`. Is it not expected that `background-color` will be affected by this?

Comment: that question is yes, but the answers in it elaborate

Answer (score 0):

[`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) has restrictions on CSS styling that you can apply to it due to [privacy reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#Styling_restrictions).

*However*, ironically, if you apply a `background` to the element *itself*, you can then override the style through the `:visited` pseudo-selector. This is the same with `:link`:

```css
a {
  background: blue; /* Required */
}

a:link {
  background: red;
  color: yellow;
}

a:visited {
  background: black;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
<br>
<a href="">link</a>
<br>
<a>link</a>
```

Comment: According to mdn's article, `background-color` is not a permitted CSS property for `:visited`? `Allowable CSS properties are color, background-color,`...

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a default state <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#Example)</sup>

```css
a:link {
  /* Specify non-transparent defaults to certain properties,
     allowing them to be styled with the :visited state */
  background-color: pink;
  color: yellow;
}

a:visited {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: hotpink;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
<br>
<a href="">link</a>-why background not work?
<br>
<a>link</a>
```

edit: you can effectively default it in `:link` too since it represents an element that has not yet been visited but notice the disclaimer in the docs:

> Styles defined by the :link pseudo-class will be overridden by any subsequent link-related pseudo-class (:active, :hover, or :visited) that has at least equal specificity

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can this be applied to the first snippet (`:link`) that can be similar?

Comment: yes it can since link represents an element that has not yet been visited ill edit

Comment: How can I explain that `a:link` that conflicts with `a:visited` is applied when `background-color` of `a:visited` is removed?

Comment: I think it makes sense to apply the style to the `a` element when you remove `background-color` in `a:visited`. However, applying the `a:link` style is contrary to the `a:visited` state and seems to make no sense.

Comment: Oh. Um I guess I’m not understanding your requirements fully. Sorry. It does make sense because it is contrary by design. One is for when it’s been visited the other is for when it has not been visited. If you want it to be styled one way regardless if it’s been visited or not use the same style rule across all pseudo classes

Comment: I’ll delete my answer because I don’t think I’m on the same page as you @tukks or understand the requirements. To me you asked why the background is not working and i answered because you need a default state to have a value

Answer (score 0):

> But in fact, the background-color property remains.

The CSS 2.1 specification states that to protect your privacy, **treat all links as unvisited** or render visited and unvisited links separately. Perhaps modern browsers treat all links as unvisited links and do something to protect your privacy. As a side effect, I suspect that the style to the `:link` pseudo-class has been applied to visited links as well. So I think this is close to a bug.

> #### 5.11.2 The link pseudo-classes: :link and :visited<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes)</sup>
>
> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently. See [P3P] for more information about handling privacy.

---

> Also, does the color of the letter return to the original blue instead of purple?

Perhaps the user agent stylesheet the browser is applying, but I couldn't find any specifications or actual stylesheets for this.

> I also found that the visited background is interfering with the link, but this isn't intuitive, but is it spec?

I'm not sure if you don't read Firefox or Chroniumu source code. At a minimum, there is no specification document that defines its behavior.