# Change CSS of an element visited by anchor

Tags: html, css, anchor

Let's say there's a link on page A: `<a href="pathToWhatEver#myAnchor">...</a>`.

The content is on page B: `<div id="myAnchor" name="myAnchor">...</div>`.

Is it possible to change the CSS of the div depending on the given anchor (myDomain.tld/pathToWhatEver#**myAnchor**)? If yes: How? There's no possibility to make this with PHP!

Comment: I think you need JS for this.

Comment: You may use the CSS :target selector

Comment: Go through this question. It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441715/set-color-for-visited-links

Comment: @enxaneta Very nice solution, thank you!

Comment: @Shahid I want to change the div, not the link...

Answer (score 1):

As @enxaneta wrote: the CSS :target selector is the right solution for me. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/3e5k1bcz/1/