# css change background-position for a:visited

Tags: html, css, anchor

I know it may sound stupid but I'm trying to change the background position for an '`anchor element`' but I get no result.

The `HTML` looks like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com/" class="first-link">Link</a><a href="http://google.com/" class="second-link"></a>
```

For the `.second-link:visited` I want to change the `background position`, I have no idea why it doesn't work.

**Update**

The css for `.second-link` looks like this:

```
.second-link { background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat -13px -124px; height: 20px; width: 15px; display: inline-block; margin: 2px 0 -6px 2px; }
```

Comment: Is second-link has `display:inline` ? If yes, `use display:inline-block` and set some `width & height`

Comment: can you create a js fiddle of the same ?

Comment: @Jashwant: it seems that I have to give up, its a [browser bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788855/google-chrome-avisited-background-image-not-working). Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no content inside your `a` tag with the `second-link` class. Therefore it will not be visible on the page as both its width and height will be `0px`. Adding some content content inside it will fix it, or if you don't want any content inside it, you'd have to set the `a` tag to `display: inline-block;` and set a width and a height on it to ensure that it is visible on the page.

Comment: The 'a' tag is rendered but it doesn't override the background-position; I'll update the question with css, please check. Thanks!