# How to Set Background for Visited Links

Tags: css, hyperlink, visited

Hi I try to set a background for visited links, but it does not work. What is going wrong?

CSS

```
ul a {display:inline-block; background:red url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSM7ZUDsq2jyP6Vz2yEmPl1HPVYQ5lUSL5MUoPvZw786K9mDfrWx9ZwYrY") center center no-repeat;
  ;color:#333;height:40px;line-height:40px;font-size:18px}
ul a:visited { background:blue url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRY3mOWqadrnwEId1cCx6fVM_ffhE1OzmnbGcRrkKPv1YGxHUZElGyGuc8") center center no-repeat;
;color:#fff}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
    <li class="t2" ><a href="http://www.adsense.com">adsense</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.budamivardi.com">budamivardi</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.jsfiddle.com">jsfiddle</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.jsfiddle.com.tr">jsfiddle</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.jsfiddle.de">jsfiddle</a></li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23ke60h5/2/)

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788855/google-chrome-avisited-background-image-not-working

Comment: is not there any solution without javascript

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331950/2274530

Comment: I'm not convinced that there's a solution *with* JavaScript; since that's the whole point of disregarding the `:visited` pseudo-selector with CSS.

Comment: I think we can just set bg color not image

Comment: It is my understanding that a privacy issue prevents this behaviour using BG images. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: yes, unfortunately right :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two extra colons and were missing a colon (your CSS was very compressed).

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/23ke60h5/5/)

I removed the background images so only the color changes.

You can now "adjust" it as you see fit.

The [CSS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) does not allow background-images on :visited links.

CSS:

```
ul a {
    display:inline-block; 
    background-color: red;
    color:yellow;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul a:visited {
    background-color: blue;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Yes, right it doesn't allow bg images but all ready I can set bg color for visited links